# asp.net core 3 and identityserver4

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I followed the [IdentityServer4 tutorial](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) to add authentication to a web api application created with **asp.net core 3 preview 9**.

My `Startup.cs` looks like this:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthorization();
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:4800";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.Audience = "api1";
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

I generate a valid JWT token and add it as **Bearer** to my requests, but I always get **401 Unauthorized**.

The same server works with a web api application created using the **.net core 2** sdk.

What's the difference?

Comment: What error do you get in the logs?

Comment: you should know that the quickstarts have not been updated for .net core 3.0 yet

Answer (score 2):

app.UseAuthentication(); has to be placed before app.UseAuthorization();

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

    }
```

[quickstarts](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/Api/Startup.cs)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
    services.AddAuthorization();

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
      .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
      {
          options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
          options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

          options.Audience = "api1";
      });

}
```